# Cannot save video to specific folder

Tags: android

I am trying to save video to specific folder like

```
Intent captureVideoIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
File videosFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Videos");
if (!videosFolder.exists()) {
    videosFolder.mkdirs(); // <----
}

String sfx = getNextName(ConstantData.RESPONSE_TYPE_VIDEO);
videoUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(videosFolder, sfx));
captureVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,videoUri);
captureVideoIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivityForResult(captureVideoIntent,1277);
```

videoUri is fine, folder Videos is created and on result when I try to read file like

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(videoUri);
ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream(8 * 8192);
....
```

I am getting exception FileNotFound, what is true, there is Videos folder but there is no saved video inside. Does anybody know what is problem and why I cannot save video to specific folder ? Video has extension .3gp and folder is always empty.

Comment: I had the same problem once. I found out that the video file is stored in some kind of asset folder which is somewhere else on the sd card. The place may change depending on which device you have. The only solution if you need the video file right in your folder is to copy the file byte by byte to your folder.
I cannot find the solution any more. Maybe you find it yourself by googling ...

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your new file name instead of the "sfx"

remove the below line and put "test.mp4" instead of the "sfx" variable, it will work

String sfx = getNextName(ConstantData.RESPONSE_TYPE_VIDEO);